# Is there a way to turn List items into links?

Tags: list, office-365, groups, outlook

I have a group list of sharepoint  groups. 
I notice that couple of end users try to click on the list names expecting them to open up Outlook from office 365.

Question: Is there a way I can turn the list items to link that launch Outlook from Office 365 web to send them email?

i.e. List Name Item 1: FinanceGroup 
     End user then clicks on "FinanceGroup"
        I want SharePoint to then launch the Outlook mail web app to send email 
        to that group.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to create a link to directly send an email, or just generic link to anywhere you wish? If just possible, it might be helpful if you can provide a picture of your case.

Comment: Trying to create a link to directly send an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list item which works as a link, open your list's settings and create a new column with the type of **Hyperlink or Picture**. Make sure the *Format URL as* is selected to *Hyperlink*.

Now to add a link, which directly opens the form to write (and to send) an email, create a new list item (or edit an existing one) so, that its Link is to `mailto:FinanceGroup@domain.com`.

Comment: I was able to create the column of Hyperlinks. thanks. But when I try:
mailto: x@abc.com, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @AlfatahKader remove the space between `mailto:` and the address `x@abc.com` => `mailto:x@abc.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works in office 365, but I would handle this by creating a calculated field, setting it to a numeric value, and showing it in your view.  This is the only non code solution that I know of.

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='mailto:",[yourgroupnamefield],"@youremail.com'>" ,[yourgroupnamefield],"</a>")
```

This is referenced here:
https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial

Here is an example of a full blown email with subject, body, etc.

```
<a href="mailto:aaa@yourdomain.com?cc=bbb@yourdomain.com&bcc=ccc@yourdomain.com&subject=Question%20About%20Your%20Department&body=Hello" target="_top">Send to Department</a>
```

Comment: where does the "=concatenate.." formula go into? 
I followed Moe's comment above and created a column that's hyperlink. However, inside the field, your formula does not work. What am I doing wrong?